# Cut folder names out of string

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How do I extract the folder named `test` from the following string?

```
TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|
```

Comment: I guess this will do:  `echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | cut -f 2 --delim=\| | xargs basename` .  Is this what you had in mind?  There are probably other solutions using `awk`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that is correct!

Comment: `echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | sed 's#.*/##;s#|(.*$##'`

Comment: I am guessing you are using a pipe-delimited format. Many CSV readers have options to specify a pipe instead of a comma as the separator.

Comment: Is the string stored in a shell variable or in a file or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you would like to get "Extra credit" for your assignment, Then use `awk`

```
echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | awk -F '[|/]' '{print $5}'
```

The `awk` option `-F` defines the field separator(s). When enclosed in brackets `[|/]` defines both `|` and `/` as a field separator. So `"test"` would be the fifth argument `'{print $5}'`

Comment: can you perhaps also tell me whether I can change the argument (null) to active after the call echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' |  ?

Comment: such as `echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | sed s/null/active/` ?

Comment: Yes, it works like this. TRUE|/home/linux/test|(active)|
Can the brackets at (active) also be removed?

Comment: It sure can - `echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | sed s/\(null\)/active/`

Comment: Thank you again, I have already rated your answer positively. However, I need at least 15 reputations. At the moment I am still a novice.

Comment: You will get there, hang in there. BTW Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Feedback: your last suggestion also works exactly as I want it to!!!!

Comment:  You can also earn another badge if you read the entire [Tour page](https://askubuntu.com/tour)

Comment: While this is generally a good solution (and `awk` is very powerful), unfortunately here it only works if `test` is the fifth substring with the separators `|/`, and I think this is dangerous when working with directories. If the directory was `/home/linux/leet/test`, this would return `leet` instead, and not the "last" directory `test`.

Comment: This would fail if any directory name in the path contained `|` (which is a valid character in a file/directory name in Unix), e.g. if one of the directory names was `foo|bar`: `'TRUE|/home/foo|bar/test|(null)|'`. You should use `awk -F '[|/]' '{print $(NF-2)}'` instead to solve that and the problem of a longer directory path, `'TRUE|/home/linux/leet/test|(null)|'`.

Answer (score 13):

Bash has a very easy way to match elements of a path (as long as your path is defined as a variable) with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Using the `${parameter##word}` construct, you search from the beginning of the line, and deletes everything up until the last match. In the case of a path, this will remove everything but the last directory, like this:

```
path='/path/to/my/stuff'; echo ${path##*/}
```

Output:

```
stuff
```

In your case though, you'll still have the final part `|(null)|` to get rid off. In this particular case, you could do a double parameter expansion, like this:

```
path='TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|'; path=${path##*/}; echo ${path%%|*}
```

Output:

```
test
```

So in this case, you first match from the beginning to the last `/` (using `${path##*/}`), and then match from the end to the last `|` (using `${path%%|*}`).

In this way, you can perform a lot of string manipulation by using only Bash builtin functionality.

Answer (score 11):

There are already two working solutions here, but I just wanted to also point out the following method, which maybe maps onto the imperative mindset more.

```bash
echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | awk -F '|' '{print $2}' | xargs basename
```

Conceptually, we 1) get the second element of the input, and 2) get the basename of that path.

`awk -F '|' '{print $2}'` splits on the `|` character, and gives you the second element, which would be `/home/linux/test`. Then, you want extract `test` from the given path, which is what the `basename` command does. The additional `xargs` is annoying from an aesthetic perspective, but is necessary because (as far as I am aware) the `basename` command can't read paths from `stdin`.

As user [@Ray points out in their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507134/cut-folder-names-out-of-string/1507199#comment2644307_1507134), `cut` would also work just as well as `awk` in this same solution.

Comment: That is awksome! From the OP's question, I did not consider variations in directory depth in my [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1507136/767056) as you and @ArturMeinild pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

Oh okay, here is a `sed` answer

```
$ echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | sed -r 's#.*/([^|]+)\|.*#\1#'
test
```

Explanation:

- `-r` use extended regex
- `s#...#..#` find and replace using `#` as an alternative delimiter to `/`
- `.*/` any number of any characters before `/` including `/` (consumes all the `/`s leaving only whatever follows the last one)
- `([^|]+)` save some characters that are not `|` to use later
- `\|.*` `|` and whatever follows it (`|` is a special character, hence escaped - not needed in `[` `]` character classes)
- `\1` the saved pattern

Comment: Nice one - `sed` always make my head spin 

Comment: @ArturMeinild maybe the `#` is a bad choice because this one makes my eyes go funny as well XD

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear from your question if you want to get the third item of an absolute path or if you want to get the last item of an absolute path.

- If you want to get the **third item of an absolute path**, you can also use the following command that makes use of `tr` and `cut`:

  ```bash
  echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | tr '|' '/' | cut -d '/' -f 5
  ```

  `tr '|' '/'` converts `|` to `/`, then `cut -d '/' -f 5` uses `/` as delimiter (`-d '/'`) and outputs the 5th element (`-f 5`).
- If you want to get the **last item of an absolute path** using `tr` and `cut` in a way similar to the above, you can also make use of the `rev` command as follows:

  ```bash
  echo 'TRUE|/home/linux/test|(null)|' | tr '|' '/' | rev | cut -d '/' -f 3 | rev
  ```

  `tr '|' '/'` converts `|` to `/`, then the first `rev` reverses the string,
  `cut -d '/' -f 3` uses `/` as delimiter (`-d '/'`) and outputs the 3rd element (`-f 3`), and finally the second `rev` reverses the string again.

---

**References**

- [`man tr`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/tr.1plan9.html)
- [`man cut`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/cut.1.html)
- [`man rev`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/rev.1.html)